# How to visualize and correlate scores obtained from GPT4 API and ChatGPT?

Tags: python, ggplot2, visualization, correlation, gpt-4

I have a question, I have obtained scores ranging from (0 to 10) resulting `GPT4 API` and `ChatGPT` prompts but they are based ran on the same biological processes. Now, I am interested to correlate these scores or find concordance. I am seeking help to how to best represent these scores or correlate scores. I tried using `ggplot` heatmap (code below) but this wasn't very helpful because I could not correlate which row (feature) belong to which column (process), but, the issue is there "Inf" values in the dataframe. I am interested to correlate each feature to each process or column, and find concordance. Probably, I am not sure, a heatmap coupled with boxplot or violin plot would help in this case?

Ps: log(Method_1 / Method_2) will return Inf if Method_2 has a value of zero, it will return -Inf if Method_1 is zero, and it will return NaN if both values are zero.

The scores are in the form of 2 R dataframes as templates given below:

### API scores

```r
dput(Method_1)
#>           A_Process B_Process C_Process D_Process E_Process F_Process G_Process
#> Feature_1         9         5         0         5         7         0         3
#> Feature_2         2         6         2         4         7         7         4
#> Feature_3         0         0         0         0         0         0         2
#> Feature_4         2         4         1         1         7         0         2
#> Feature_5         0         6         0         0         6         7         2
#>           H_Process I_Process J_Process
#> Feature_1         4         6         2
#> Feature_2         0         0         0
#> Feature_3         5         7         7
#> Feature_4         3         5         6
#> Feature_5         3         5         6
```

### ChatGPT scores

```
dput(Method_2)
#>           A_Process B_Process C_Process D_Process E_Process F_Process G_Process
#> Feature_1         1         5         2         3         7         2         1
#> Feature_2         9         6         1         3         6         7         0
#> Feature_3         9         7         2         6         6         2         3
#> Feature_4         0         8         6         6         8         7         4
#> Feature_5         8         5         2         2         6         6         3
#>           H_Process I_Process J_Process
#> Feature_1         1         3         8
#> Feature_2         0         5         5
#> Feature_3         4         4         7
#> Feature_4         4         4         7
#> Feature_5         5         4         6
```

```
log_ratios <- log(Method_1 / Method_2)

# Heatmap visualization
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

# Assuming 'log_ratios' is a dataframe where the rownames are features
log_ratios$Feature <- rownames(log_ratios)
log_ratios_melted <- melt(log_ratios, id.vars = "Feature")

# Now plotting
ggplot(log_ratios_melted, aes(variable, Feature, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red", mid = "white", midpoint = 0) +
  theme_minimal() +
  xlab("Process") +
  ylab("Feature") +
  ggtitle("Heatmap of Concordance")

ggplot(log_ratios_melted, aes(x = Feature, y = value)) +
  geom_violin(trim = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free_y") + # Ensure 'variable' is the column with process names
  theme_minimal() +
  xlab("Feature") +
  ylab("Log Ratio") +
  ggtitle("Question wise distribution of concordance")
```

[Probable data presentation visualization](https://imgur.com/fDRUw1n)

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to look at the log ratios? Perhaps another to metric for correlation would be more useful to you. Relevance scores are kind of arbitrary by definition (typically calculated by something with vector similarity), so they don't have much of a physical meaning. Would simply taking the average of the scores work for y you? 

However, if you want to avoid infinities:

```epsilon = 1e-8;
log_ratios <- log(a + epsilon) - log(b + epsilon) 
```
Could work, or you could simply set log(0) to be zero in your calculation.

Comment: @A10 thank you for the response. There is no specific reason to look at the log ratios. I just started exploring using this calculations. Any suggestions will be helpful to build test cases.

Comment: Truthfully, it depends on what your goals might be with this metric. However, based on the heat map example you've shown, I expect something like the average score between both LLMs will be a lot more intuitive for that heatmap, and likely in general. 

How are those scores calculated/distributed for each model/measurement? That may help guide your decision for a more complex comparison between the scoring of the two models.

Comment: @A10 In this study, “prompt engineering” played a critical role in harnessing the capabilities of LLMs for candidate feature or gene prioritization. Here a key aspect of our approach consisted in requesting LLMs (ChatGPT4 and GPT4 API) to score on a scale from 0 to 10 each feature against a series of statements (here annotated as process). Those statements or process were structured around three primary biological themes, for instance: (i) Relevance as a biomarker, (ii) Therapeutic relevance, and (iii) Biological significance.

Comment: @A10, Each statement was scored independently, obviating the need for a specific order in the prompts. Although we considered weighted scoring based on the perceived importance of each theme, we opted for equal weighting across all themes to align with the translational focus of this project.

Comment: @A10 `Scoring criteria:
0—No evidence found.
1–3—Very limited evidence.
4–6—Some evidence, but needs validation or is limited to certain conditions.
7–8—Good evidence, used or proposed for some clinical applications.
9–10—Strong evidence, firmly established as a useful biomarker.`

Comment: That scoring system feels fairly arbitrary. That isn't a bad thing -- that just means you've got a lot of freedom in how you want to display and play with those results. In this case I see no reason why an average score between however many different methods you choose. That will give you something a lot more intuitive then a logarithmic scale, and intuitive is always better than fancy. That being said, check the distribution of your rankings, and if you really want to be careful you can check if your aggregate view has a similar distribution, which may give you a more "natural" comparison.